# How to decrease the margin size of the number of line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've a project on Visual Studio 2019 (with Resharper Ultimate enable) and has been a terrible experience because I can't read the entire line of the code (I've myopia so my font size is 15~18)

But I see that this margin occupies so much space. 
[image]

Is there any way to change this? I want to keep the number of lines.

Comment: Have a look at text editor options in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-general?view=vs-2019) and disable unnecessary margins

Answer (score 4):

For vs 2022 you must set this:

Disable the "Inheritance Margin": Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Inheritance Margin -> Uncheck "Show inheritance margin"

[image]

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?view=vs-2022#inheritance-margin)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32904409)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the menu *Tools* and select the *Options* submenu.
Then go to the *Text Editor* node, expand it and go to *All Languages* node.
Here you will find the Line Numbers option.
Just remove the check to hide the line numbers

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep line numbers, but want to save space, go into Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General and from there you can uncheck Selection margin and Indicator margin

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `glyph margin` in Settings. (I'm currently using VS Code in ubuntu 18.04... should be similar in other OS I think
[In settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRqso.png)

It will remove the excess space used for adding breakpoints,etc
Before:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVbhi.png)
After:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jQo6.png)

Comment: This question asks about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.